Collision Checking using Moveit (python wrapper) for a set of Joint Positions
I have a set of robot joint positions which I found by sweeping through the allowed joint positions with a fixed delta. This gives me about a set of ~2 million joint positions. Now, I want to check which of these joint positions might result in self collision and eliminate them from my set. I just care about the joint position under consideration and not the start and intermediate positions that will get me to that particular joint position. Is there a easy and fast way to do it with moveit and ros? I would like it to be fast so I don't have to wait forever to get the results.
Version: Moveit with ROS noetic (Ubuntu 20.04)
